# N2O. Как получить и отобразить настоящее время

Tags: java

Необходимо получить время (настоящее) и далее сравнить его с тем, что хранится в других объектах. Всё это в N2O на странице. 
Хотел сделать что-то в роде такого

```
<ctrl:hidden id="realTime">
                <ctrl:set-value-expression><![CDATA[
            realTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH").format(new Date());
                            ]]>
                </ctrl:set-value-expression>
            </ctrl:hidden>
```

Но это не отрабатывает (не отображается на странице)

Есть какой-либо подход для получения времени системы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением оказался следующий код

```
<ctrl:masked-input id="someId" label="Какой-то лейбл" label-style="width:15px;" mask="DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm">
    <ctrl:set-value-expression on-load="true">
        moment.tz(getTimezone()).utc().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm')
    </ctrl:set-value-expression>
</ctrl:masked-input>`
```